# Practical risk of using static IV amongst sparsely duplicated values?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm working on a legacy project with zero security (plain text database storage) and there are real constraints on development time and ability to tinker with the existing database structure. They have asked me to encrypt certain values.

After much research, I decided on AES-256-CBC encryption. I decided on a hard-coded, single IV because all of the keys being encrypted are completely unique and we can't afford the overhead of adding additional column(s) to store IV(s) if not absolutely necessary. But now they want to encrypt an additional column that contains sparsely duplicated values (e.g. of 10,000 rows, there may be 20-30 duplicates).

Seemingly the most obvious flaw in encrypting this additional column is that duplicate values will share the same encrypted value, and thus cracking one results in cracking duplicates. They are not concerned about this at all, since this value isn't particularly 'valuable.' But I have read that there is a risk that a hacker could better predict how you are encrypting your data using an identical IV + value pair, which could subsequently lead to easier decryption of unrelated values. Is that a legitimate concern I should relay to them? Given constraints on dev time and ability to modify the existing database structure, is this an outsized risk worth considering?

Comment: You don't need a dedicated column for IVs. Just store IV and ciphertext together (i.e., simply concatenate them). IVs have a known length, so it's trivial to pick both apart when decrypting.

Comment: Agree with @Peter

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be a question for crypto.stackexchange.com as it is not directly related to programming API's etc.?

Anyway, I'm wondering against whom are you defending your (plaintext) data?

- malicious users of your application that may at some point use (SQL) Injection
- system/database administrators or hosting provider that can read/modify the database or backups

And what risks are you trying to mitigate with this encryption, e.g.:

- attacker duplicating records from/to a part of the database that they can access through the application, thus tricking the application into en-/decrypting it
- statistical analysis ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis )

This encryption function might be reused in the coming months and years by other developers for other database fields, or even other applications, so why not design it for safe reuse by deriving the necessary IV bits from the result of a hash function (e.g.: SHA-3) over the following concatenated inputs:

1. The Database name
2. The Schema name
3. The Table name
4. The Column name
5. The ID / Primary Key of the record

Disclaimer: I'm no crypto expert so don't take my word for it, no guarantees whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a couple of things you can do each of them require different implementation efforts.

1. As Peter already mentioned - you can glue your IV at the beginning of your ciphertext. Hopefully this will not blow the total length limit defined for the column. Note: the length of the ciphertext will be bigger due to: 1) CBC mode 2) IV length 3) BASE 64 or whatever encoding you use.
2. You can derive IV from another key attribute from the same record that is unique and does not change.
3. Sometimes it is necessary to use deterministic encryption in the databases (encryption with the same, static IV). This happens usually, when the columns value needs to be used in some SQL WHERE conditions. If this is the case, just use some static IV value and accept the consequences.